# Getting the selected Items in EnhacnedGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have created a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid. I want to fetch the selected Item in the grid.
grid.selection.getSelected() is the method that I am using to fetch the selected rows with the attributes and their corresponding values.

But this function returns an array of array(properties and their values).
I want to return an array that contains only properties and values(not in array).

Please guide

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The selection returned from  grid.selection.getSelected() will give you all the rows selected, each row has multiple columns, so each row will have many key/value pairs (where key is the field id and value is the displayed cell value).  So a one dimensional array of a two dimensional representation of data is a little difficult.  Do you have more specifics in mind?  I could help with the algorithm if you do.